# VBA Access Help - Multiple lines for one user, need to group them and send only one email to the person as opposed to an email per line

Tags: vba, ms-access

I created a VBA script to send emails from a query of those tickets that are overdue. When I run the program below, it generates an email per overdue item. However, if a person has 4 tickets overdue it generated 4 emails for the same person. How could I modify the code so that if my table has multiple lines for one user, it could group them and send only one email to the person as opposed to an email per line:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Sub SendSerialEmail()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim rec As DAO.Recordset
Dim emailTo As String
Dim nameemployee As String
Dim emailSubject As String
Dim emailText As String
Dim strQry As String
Dim aHead(1 To 6) As String
Dim aRow(1 To 6) As String
Dim aBody() As String
Dim lCnt As Long
Dim outApp As Outlook.Application
Dim outMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim outStarted As Boolean

'Create the header row
aHead(1) = "Ticket#"
aHead(2) = "Summary"
aHead(3) = "Ticket Status"
aHead(4) = "Date Created"
aHead(5) = "# Business Days Open"
aHead(6) = "Assigned To"

lCnt = 1
ReDim aBody(1 To lCnt)
aBody(lCnt) = "<HTML><body><table border='2'><tr><th>" & Join(aHead, "</th><th>") & "</th></tr>"


On Error Resume Next
Set outApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
On Error GoTo 0
If outApp Is Nothing Then
Set outApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
outStarted = True
End If


Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT email, full_name FROM     OverdueTerminationTickets")
Do Until rs.EOF
Set outMail = outApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set rec = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT ID, title, full_name, created,     workdaysopen " & _
     "FROM OverdueTerminationTickets WHERE email = '" & rs!email & "'")
'loop through rec to build email body, array object is not needed.
Do Until rec.EOF
    strRecs = strRecs & rec!ID & ", " & rec!Title & ", " & rec!full_name & ", " & _
        rec!CREATED & ", " & rec!workdaysopen & vbCrLf
    rec.MoveNext
Loop
'set To, CC, Subject, concatenate strRecs to header string for HTMLBody and send email
strRecs = ""
rec.Close
rs.MoveNext
Loop

If outStarted Then
outApp.Quit
End If

Set outMail = Nothing
Set outApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: check that current email = last email (store in variable). if so, concatenate items to the body, instead of making new email.

Comment: Do you have a table of Users? Why not save only UserID into OverdueTerminationTickets instead of repeating user info in multiple records? As it is now, have to use User full name to identify users. Names are poor unique identifiers. Or depend that each email associates with only one user and use email as unique identifier as suggested by @ScottHoltzman.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have two recordsets, one recordset should be a set of unique user identifiers, in this case the email, then apply user identifier filter to rec inside rs loop. I don't think need to repeat fullname on every record line (nor other data such as title and name if specific to the addressee).

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT email, fullname FROM OverdueTerminalTickets")
Do Until rs.EOF
    Set outMail = outApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Set rec = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT ID, title, name, created, workdaysopen " & _
         "FROM OverdueTerminationTickets WHERE email = '" & rs!email & "'")
    'loop through rec to build email body, array object is not needed.
    Do Until rec.EOF
        strRecs = strRecs & rec!ID & ", " & rec!title & ", " & rec!name & ", " & _
            rec!created & ", " & rec!workdaysopen & vbCrLf
        rec.MoveNext
    Loop    
    'set To, CC, Subject, concatenate strRecs to header string for HTMLBody and send email
    ...
    strRecs = ""
    rec.Close
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

If you want data to align in columns, use HTML tags in strRecs concatenation to build tabular structure. Or go back to using the array inside rec loop as you originally did - I've just never gone that route.

The point is, with two recordsets need a loop within a loop. An alternative structure could use only one recordset ordered by email then a variable set to email and `If Then` code checks when email in record does not agree with variable - sends email and resets variables and starts building new message body. There is only one loop with this approach.

Comment: Hi June7,
Thanks for your reply!! I am having trouble with where to insert the code you have proposed? Your help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: It replaces everything from `Set db ` to `Set db `. Can Close and Set objects to nothing if you want but VBA should do that automatically when procedure terminates. Exactly what difficulty are you having? I edited my answer a little. Be sure to add appropriate code in place of ellipses.

Comment: I really appreciate your replies!! When I input the new code into the program, I am getting a compile error stating the "strRecs" variable is not defined. Code has been updated above!

Comment: Then add a Dim statement at top of procedure.